# ML syntax dichotomy : dynamic vs static

Tags: function, syntax, ml

A dichotomy in ML syntax:

1. We apply functions on dynamic values like this: `(function
   param_value)`.
2. We apply function on static values [types] like this:
   `'a list`. - Here `list` is the function, and `'a` is the parameter.

So the order in the syntax is reversed. While I would be okay with any of the orders, the inconsistency hurts my eyes. I suspect that this is just a design mistake. Do you know of any reason of it?

---

ATS [which can be thought of as the next generation ML] uses the same order [1] at both levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no deep reason for this syntactic discrepancy, as far as I can tell. Writing type application in postfix notation is somewhat convenient, because unary type constructors are common, and the notation allows multiple applications like `int option list` to be written without parentheses, and to read naturally (in English). Nevertheless, it seems to me that nobody is too fond of this syntax, and I doubt anybody would pick it again today. Once you move to dependent types, you need uniform syntax anyway.